Joke.map is not a function in an react
export default App
In this code it is showing error that joke.map is not a function  .Pls help me find the solution
I checked the api endpoints and also the function
         import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [Joke,setJokes]=useState([])
  
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    axios.get(' /api/jokes')
          .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
              setJokes(response.data);
           
          })
          .catch((error=>{
            console.log(error)
          }))
  })

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Omkar Mundhe</h1>
      <p>JOKES:{Joke.length}</p>
      {
        Joke.map((joke,index)=>{
          <div key={joke.id}>
            <h3>{joke.setup}</h3>
            <p>{joke.punchline}</p>
          </div>
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}

And In console I am not getting any response but on checking in postman i am getting the below html code
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="module">
        import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh"
RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
    </script>

    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx?t=1719029620018"></script>
</body>

</html>

the console log

What was the response you got back?  Are you sure it was an array?  You logged it -- show us a section of the log.

Can you check why the api endpoint has space in the beginning? And also when you’re logging the response what do you see? Can you share the log?

I checked the api points .By mistake it was typo from my side .But still the error is same.Also there is no log in console what I am getting .But when I checked it in postman I am getting a html file in response

<!doctype html>



<script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<


What makes you think you'd get an API response for the relative URL of /api/jokes? That simply looks to me like you're receiving the default HTML response from the Vite dev server which is pretty much what I'd expect without a proxy involved

You can use Map( ) function for "array" type only. So, Before updating to Jokes array, check the API response structure, If data is array then update it into Jokes.
 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchJokes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/jokes');
    console.log(response);
    
    // Check if response.data exists and is an array
    if (response?.data && Array.isArray(response.data)) {
      setJokes(response.data);
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid data received from API');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching jokes:', error);
  }
};

fetchJokes();
}, []);

I hope this will help you.
